# When using the shell method to compute volume, why not use exact circumference?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm going through MIT's online calculus course, and often we're asked to calculate the volume of a 2d object that is rotated around an axis to create a 3d solid.

Given the x-y plane, there's usually two ways to set the problem up: either integrate over $dx$ or $dy$.  Depending on how the problem is set up, one way will be called the "disk" method (summing up a bunch of cylinders, each with a tiny height), and the other will be called the "shell" method (summing up a bunch of tubes, each with a tiny thickness).

For an example problem, you can check the 42min mark of [the lecture video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeXp1zC6Hls), but I'll describe it here.  We're taking the line $y = e^x$ over the interval $x = [0,1]$, meaning it's also over the interval $y = [1, e]$, and rotating that around the y-axis to create a bowl shape.  The problem asks to find the volume of that bowl.

I got the correct answer by using the shell method, and setting the problem up like so:

$$\int_0^1 2 \pi x (e^1 - e^x) dx$$

where $(e^1 - e^x)$ is the height of each "tube" (or "shell"), dx is the thickness of each tube, and $2 \pi x$ is the circumference of each tube.

But I had the thought that $2 \pi x$ is NOT the actual, intuitive circumference of each tube, $2 \pi (x + \frac{dx}{2})$ is because it's actually the midpoint of each rectangle that's rotating around the y-axis to generate the circumference.  First, am I correct?  And if so, why are we able to just disregard this term?

Comment: Well, you can view the method as computing the derivative of the volume with respect to $x$. In this case you get the **exact** expression $\frac{ d V(x)} {dx} = 2 \pi x (e^1 - e^x)$. Then you solve the 'differential equation'.

Comment: Effectively, if you use $2\pi(x + dx/2)$ then, when multiplying by $dx$ for the thickness, you will end up with a $dx^2$ term added on from the usual expression.  This is "especially infinitesimal" and is always taken to be zero.  For example, its integral would still have one infinitesimal "dimension" and thus be negligible compared to the whole answer.  This is not a precise statement but it is probably not any worse than the derivation of the shell method that you may have seen, and if it is, then you can try modifying that computation to see what I mean by negligible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *almost* use the $dx$ in the integral as a variable that is added and multiplied, but you have to be careful when you do so.

One way to look at the underlying reasoning is like this: What we're really doing is taking a sum of the form
$$
S=\sum_{i=1}^n 2\pi \left(x_i+\frac{\Delta x}{2}\right) h(x_i)\Delta x
$$
(where $h(x)$ is the height of each shell) and taking a limit in which $\Delta x\to 0$ and $n\to\infty$.  We can write this sum as
$$
S=\sum_{i=1}^n 2\pi x_i h(x_i)\Delta x
+ \Delta x\sum_{i=1}^n \pi h(x_i)\Delta x
$$
Taking the limit as $\Delta x\to 0$, these sums become
$$
S=\int_0^1 2\pi \,x \,h(x)\,dx
+ 0\cdot \int_0^1 \pi\, h(x)\,dx
$$
Or, in other words: 
$$
S=\int_0^1 2\pi \,x \,h(x)\,dx
$$

---

An even less formal way to think about it is to note that these shells are "really thin", so that using the approximation $(x+\frac{\Delta x}{2})\approx x$ doesn't change our result "noticeably".

Comment: Great answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First note that speaking of $dx$ as a nonzero, infinitesimal thickness is problematic. We must speak of a limit process here.
If we consider tubes of positive thickness $\Delta x$, then we only get a rough approximation of the volume: Each tube has volume $(\pi(x+\Delta x)^2-\pi x^2)\cdot f(\xi)$ where we choose $\xi\in[x,x+\Delta x]$ to our liking (e.g. $\xi = x$ or $\xi=x+\frac12\Delta x$ or so that $f(\xi)$ becomes maximal or becomes minimal). Simplifying, the tube volume becomes $$(2\pi x\Delta x +\pi(\Delta x)^2)f(\xi)=2\pi x\Delta x f(\xi) +\pi(\Delta x)^2f(\xi)$$
When we sum over these volumes and then take the limit as we let $\Delta x\to 0$ (and the number $n$ of summands $\to\infty$, the following happens:

- For continuous $f$, the distinction between $f(\xi)$ and $f(x)$ becomes negligible
- For bounded $f$, the contribution of the summands $\pi(\Delta x)^2f(\xi)$ becomes negligible because we have $n$ summands of size $\sim \frac 1{n^2}$
- The sum turns into an integral $\int_a^b 2\pi xf(x)\,\mathrm dx$

In principle the same argumentation takes place with the disk method and it already takes places when you show that the area under a function graph is given by an integral.

Answer (score 0):

Expand what you have: $$\int_0^1 2\pi (x + \frac{dx}{2}) (e^1 - e^x) dx $$
$$\int_0^1 2\pi x (e^1 - e^x) dx + \int_0^1 \pi dx (e^1 - e^x) dx $$
$$\int_0^1 2\pi x (e^1 - e^x) dx + \int_0^1 (\pi (e^1 - e^x) dx) dx $$

This second term is very interesting, we have two $dx$s. I'm not entirely sure what this means formally (I can't seem to write it as a Riemann sum). But it appears that you're integrating a function where every value is infinitesimal, and since you're integrating over a finite interval, the result should also be infinitesimal?

It reminds me of the ring theory approach to calculus, where you include an $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon^2 = 0$. The $dx$ behaves like this $\epsilon$, in that when there's just one, it's infinitesimal, but still important, but squaring it makes it negligible.